# Reentering a route doesn't load content

Tags: ember.js

I've got a route set up like this:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('settings/user', {into: 'application', controller: 'User'});
        this.render('settings/user_left', {outlet: 'left_menu'});
    },
    setupController: function(controller, user){
        this.controllerFor('users').set('content', App.User.find());
    }
}
```

Controller is:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: 'users',
    contentBinding: 'controllers.users.firstObject',
});
```

If I navigate to `/user` it's ok. If I then navigate to somewhere else and press BACK (or just open the route), content of the template is never filled out, even though App.User.find() returns data properly and controllerFor also finds a controller. I think I'm doing something wrong with controllers but can't find what... If the page is refreshed it works fine of course.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008047/how-can-we-reload-a-route-ember-js-versoin-1-0-0-rc-1

Comment: Do you get "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications"