# How can we reload a route Ember JS (versoin 1.0.0-rc.1)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a condition where my route:

`application.com/#/sample/:id` is redirected back to `application.com/#/sample/:id`
For example, 
`application.com/#/sample/1` gets an event which redirects to `application.com/#/sample/2`

This does not cause a reload. Has any one got this case fixed?

Actually I am having a case
`application.com/#/parent/123/sample/1` causing redirect to `application.com/#/parent/123/sample/2`

Event is received by `ParentRouter` to `transitionTo("parent.sample",{id:2})`.

What I get in the log is:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. Its was a NULL handling issue in the handlebars.
I made some additional check for nulls. It works now.

There have been some similar issues filed on Github, we can always reload the current route and redirect back to any route.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For transit into route manually, you may try these two methods:

1. For routes with **different** name:

   `App.Router.router.transitionTo(name, params);`
2. For routes with **same** name:

   `App.Router.router.getHandler(name).enter();`

   It should be identical to call `enter` event of route. (I'm not sure)

Comment: What about : Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications. Seems like there are too many refresh events happening and causing the view to go awry ?

Comment: Can you setup a demo in jsfiddle for us to debug? Thanks.

Comment: A similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682550/reentering-a-route-doesnt-load-content